# Set fontSize legend ChartView QML

Tags: qt, charts, qml, qt-creator

I need your help. I'm doing a ChartView in qml, and I cant't set the font size. I read the documentations, but I didn't find any solution.

Is there a method to set legend font size ??

```
ChartView {
    id:chartView
    title: "Haccp Data"
    theme: ChartView.ChartThemeDark
    backgroundColor: "black";
    width: parent.width;
    height: parent.height
    anchors.fill: parent
    antialiasing: true;
    visible: true
    legend.markerShape: Legend.MarkerShapeCircle

    ....
}
```

I've seen that there's a property :

> legend.font: Font.pointSize(8) //for example

but changing this property value doesn't have any effects.
Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `legend.font.pointSize: 120`? (I don't have charts installed, but this is what I would expect from the docs) If it has no effect, try to set it on `Component.onCompleted: legend.font.pointSize = 120`

Comment: Also output `legend.font.pixelSize` - if it is set, this will be used regardless of the `legend.font.pointSize` (see: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-font.html)

Comment: @derM your solutions works, could you answer my question that i flag right question ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the documentation, the right syntax is:

```
legend.font.pointSize: 120
```

If by chance you have also set

```
legend.font.pixelSize
```

this setting has priority as stated in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-font.html).

Answer (score 0):

Note that the straightforward

```
legend.font.pointSize: 120
```

doesn't work when you have specified a theme for the chart, as was done in the original question.

In this case the

```
Component.onCompleted...
```

method as suggested by @derM is the only workaround I've found that works. Thanks @derM.